# How to calculate the Sample Variance for the Kruskal Wallis Test (with Ties)

Tags: self-study, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

The ranks are:

Rank Group 1: 13, 15.5, 18, 21.5, 9.5

Rank Group 2: 4.5, 11.5, 18, 20, 18, 6.5

Rank Group 3: 3, 21.5, 11.5, 9.5, 15.5, 14

Rank Group 4: 6.5, 8, 2, 4.5, 1

So the means of ranks are: 15.5, 13.0833, 12.5, and 4.4.

The mean of the means is: 11.5.

My instructor got 41.9286 for S^2(R), or the sample variance of the 22 adjusted ranks. How exactly do you get this number? I'm really confused by the formula we use to calculate it, like do we just use the rank means or all of the ranks? I understand everything else, it's just this last bit of the problem I'm stuck on!

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

This appears to be a [tag:self-study] question.  If that is the case, please read our [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and tag your question as well.